# Telegram and FB link Preview

Tags: html, wordpress, facebook, telegram, yoast

I'm trying to setup my site so that it is ready for sharing on Social Media platforms such as Facebook & Telegram. At present, shared links aren't showing any preview images. I want to make use of these for maximum exposure.

I have the following og tags:

```
   <meta property="og:image" content="https://voaustralia.com/wp-content/uploads/money.jpg" />
   <meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://voaustralia.com/wp-content/uploads/money.jpg" />
```

what`s the problem?

As far as I am aware the above should be enough for my images to show as previews. I'm even using the Yoast SEO plugin which generates these tags automatically.

Here's an example page, that I'm not seeing any preview images for:  [link](https://voaustralia.com/%DB%B1%DB%B0%D8%B4%D8%BA%D9%84-%D9%BE%D9%88%D9%84%E2%80%8C%D8%B3%D8%A7%D8%B2-%D8%AF%D9%87%D9%87-%D8%A2%DB%8C%D9%86%D8%AF%D9%87-%D8%B1%D8%A7-%D8%A8%D8%B4%D9%86%D8%A7%D8%B3/)

Comment: This is a really poorly formatted question. To give people a better chance of giving you the help you need, please try to write a proper question (eg not a question as a title), along with examples of what issue you are experiencing. Try to describe clearly what result(s) you are getting compared to what you are expecting / hoping for. Demos, and real code examples go a looooooong way, toward getting a satisfactory answer.

Comment: You can try https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/

Comment: @Sean I already mentioned that in my answer. But, yes, that really should be the tool people use for this kind of thing.

Comment: ok i didnt know about FB caching. what about telegram?

Comment: telegram link preview?

Comment: @NavidM I imagine any service would do the same. It'd be insane not to. Have you looked for a telegram link? Will you be accepting my answer? ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facebook in particular uses a heavy cache on links.

So if you tried to share a link when the image tag wasn't setup or was wrong, then new link shares will use this cached data, rather than retry for the preview image.

You should really use the Facebook testing tool to make sure that you haven't actually already fixed the issue. I tested your link for example and that shows a preview image: [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fvoaustralia.com%2F%25DB%25B1%25DB%25B0%25D8%25B4%25D8%25BA%25D9%2584-%25D9%25BE%25D9%2588%25D9%2584%25E2%2580%258C%25D8%25B3%25D8%25A7%25D8%25B2-%25D8%25AF%25D9%2587%25D9%2587-%25D8%25A2%25DB%258C%25D9%2586%25D8%25AF%25D9%2587-%25D8%25B1%25D8%25A7-%25D8%25A8%25D8%25B4%25D9%2586%25D8%25A7%25D8%25B3%2F)

Heres a tool for testing several preview systems / networks at once. It's a 3rd party tool so it may well still use caching. You'll have to give it a try and see how useful it proves to be: https://richpreview.com/

Comment: I marked your answer. but how much time social networks like FB and Telegram need to clear old cache? I think i waited for two weeks

Comment: Have you tried the tool that I gave in my answer? If everything works with that tool, then you should see any new shared links on Facebook will display the image. This isn't applied retrospectively. Previously share links already on Facebook won't suddenly show images. It only show for links shared after you fix any issues.

Comment: yes i tried https://richpreview.com. that shows correct on the web but in telegram thumbnail doesn`t show anyway. another websites preview works correctly but this one...

Answer (score 9):

Both Telegram and Facebook use OG-mata tags ([http://ogp.me](http://ogp.me/)) for getting information about your webpage. For example:

```
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="My site title">
<meta property="og:title" content="My page title">
<meta property="og:description" content="My page description">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://example.com/my-page-url">
<meta property="og:locale" content="en_US">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/myImage.jpg">
```

Also you should insert "prefix" attribute inside the `<html>` tag. For example:

```
<html prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
```

Finally, if you made those changes but still don't see any changes in Telegram and Facebook, it means that they have cached old versions of your pages. You can use their special tools for cache clearing.

**Telegram** Use [webpagebot](https://telegram.me/webpagebot), here you can send your page URL and Telegram will grab your page data again.

**Facebook** Go to [Open Graph Object Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug). Here you can type your page URL and click "Fetch new scrape information". Facebook will grab your page data again.